# How to fetch a row which is related to multiple rows in another table?

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have some tables:

#### ws_shop_product

```
CREATE TABLE `ws_shop_product` (
     `product_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
     `product_title` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_general_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`product_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=14499 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_general_ci
```

#### ws_system_admin

```
CREATE TABLE `ws_system_admin` (
     `admin_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
     `admin_username` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
     `admin_password` char(40) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`admin_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=14 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

#### ws_shop_product-updated

```
CREATE TABLE `ws_shop_product-updated` (
     `updated_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
     `updated_product` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
     `updated_admin` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
     `updated_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`updated_id`),
 KEY `updated_product` (`updated_product`),
 KEY `updated_admin` (`updated_admin`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=42384 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_general_ci
```

---

Whenever a `product` has been changed in the CMS, one row 
will insert into the `ws_shop_product-updated` which keep
the `admin` ID, `product` ID and `date`.

Some data:

```
product_id    product_title
----------    -------------
         1    iPhone 5
```

```
updated_product    updated_admin    updated_date
---------------    -------------    ------------
              1              301    2013-04-13 00:00:00
              1              302    2013-04-15 00:00:00
              1              303    2013-04-16 00:00:00
```

**Now my question is: How can I fetch products with latest update information?**

```
product_id    product_title    latest_admin_id    latest_date
----------    -------------    ---------------    -----------
         1    iPhone 5         303                2013-04-16 00:00:00
```

Comment: Your question is very well formed, but it is true that it would be even better to show you have tried something first. You should look into the [`GROUP BY`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-functions.html) clause as well as the [`MAX()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/example-maximum-column.html) function. Please check these manual pages, you might find the solution yourself. If not, please come back with what you have tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you are using mysql, you can use mysql's special (and non-portable) group by functionality to produce this fairly simple query:

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT p.product_id, p.product_title,
    u.updated_admin latest_admin_id, u.updated_date latest_date
  FROM ws_shop_product p
  LEFT JOIN `ws_shop_product-updated` u ON u.updated_product = p.product_id
  ORDER BY u.updated_date DESC) x
GROUP BY 1
```

This query will return all products, even if they don't have a row in the "updated" table - returning `null` values for the "latest" columns when there's no such row.

The reason this works is that (for mysql only) when not all non-aggregated columns are named in the group by, mysql returns the *first* row found for each unique combination of values of columns named in the group by clause. By ordering the data in the subquery latest-first, the first row found for each product_id will be the latest.

Comment: **+1** PERFECT, with fast result, but really I didn't understand your query, it's very strange to me. I need to improve my mysql/sql, could you give me some start point/book/manual or something else? Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a query like this:

```
SELECT
  p.product_id,
  p.product_title,
  u.updated_admin latest_admin_id,
  u.updated_date latest_date
FROM
  `ws_shop_product-updated` u INNER JOIN ws_shop_product p
  ON u.updated_product = p.product_id
WHERE
  (u.updated_product, u.updated_date) IN
  (SELECT   updated_product, MAX(updated_date)
   FROM     `ws_shop_product-updated`
   GROUP BY product_id)
```

Please see fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a950a/1).

The subquery will return the maximum updated_date for each product, the outer query will return all columns of all rows that have the maximum updated_date for every product.

Comment: When I run this query in phpMyAdmin, it takes a very looooong time.

Answer (score -1):

You can try this :

```
      WITH    CTE ( PRODUCTID, PRODUCT_TITLE )
                  AS ( SELECT   *
                       FROM     dbo.ws_shop_product
                     ),
                CTE2 ( updated_id, updated_product, updated_admin, updated_date, ROW )
                  AS ( SELECT   * ,
                                ROW = ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY UPDATED_PRODUCT ORDER BY UPDATED_DATE DESC )
                       FROM     dbo.ws_shop_productupdated
                     )
            SELECT  A.* ,
                    B.UPDATED_ADMIN ,
                    UPDATED_DATE
            FROM    CTE A
                    JOIN CTE2 B ON A.PRODUCTID = B.UPDATED_PRODUCT
            WHERE   ROW = 1
```

Comment: -1 This is a **mysql** question. SQL Server syntax is useless.